# Is overriding generic_visit() more effective when transforming multiple types of AST Nodes within one inner class?

Tags: python, syntax, abstract-syntax-tree

Suppose you have an inner class

```
class SomeTransformer(ast.NodeTransformer):
    
        def visit_Global(self, node):
                *transform AST*
                super().generic_visit(node)
                return node

        def visit_Assign(self, node):
                *transform AST*
                super().generic_visit(node)
                return node

        def visit_FunctionDef(self, node):
                *transform AST*
                super().generic_visit(node)
                return node
```

Would it be more effective to override `generic_visit()` in a way below, because in the first version the whole tree will be traversed completely three times, looking for nodes of specific type only, while in the second version it will be transformed in a single traversal?

```
class SomeTransformer(ast.NodeTransformer):
            
  def generic_visit(self, node):

    for child in ast.iter_child_nodes(node):
        if isinstance(child, ast.Global):
            *transform AST*
        if isinstance(child, ast.Assign):
            *transform AST*
        if isinstance(child, ast.FunctionDef):
            *transform AST*

    return node
```

Comment: This assumption is not correct: "in the first version the whole tree will be traversed completely three times"

Comment: @rici So are you saying that in the first version everything happens within one traversal? Because you can see the `super().generic_visit(node)` being called in every overriden method. I thought this means that it explores all the children of a particular node. And since it's being called three times, I assumed that it traverses the tree 3 times, each time looking only for nodes of the type I specified.

Comment: Yes, there is only one traversal. I think you don't have the correct mental model for this traverse. It's a simple recursive depth-first tree walk. Note that `iter_child_nodes` is correctly named. It is not `iter_descendant_nodes`. It does not visit anything other than direct children. The recursive walk must be implemented in the action performed on each child.

Comment: Also, it is not possible for `child` to be an instance of more than one of `Global`, `Assign` and `FunctionDef`, so there's no point in writing independent `if` statements. If you wanted to implement your alternative 2 with `if` statements, you'd use a chain of `if` ... `elif`, or you could use a `match` statement (which will match classes). But the way `NodeVisitor` is actually implemented might be faster if you have more than a couple of types you're interested in. (Or it might not; the time difference won't be huge. But it will almost certainly be easier to write. And to read.)